# Parameterised, but type-safe keys in JSON processing

Tags: haskell, aeson

How do I express the following idea in Haskell? While, the syntax is completely made up, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- My app has highly nested core data-types with each "level" having FromJson/ToJson instances
- The JSON API powering the UI has the ability to manipulate individual "levels of nesting", eg. to edit the address, you don't need to edit the complete order.
- However, I want to make sure that along with the data that was modified by the UI, the complete order is also sent back. This ensures that, if the edit has resulted in some dependent field in another part of the object being changed, it is communicated back to the UI.

**Edit:** The core question is not about the app logic, per-se. The core question is how to represent JSON keys in a type-safe manner while having the ability to parameterise over them. The simple solution is to have a different concrete type for each API return type, eg `{orderItems :: [OrderItem], order :: Order}` or `{address :: Address, order :: Order}` or `{email :: Email, customer :: Customer}`. But these will get repetitive quickly. I want to have a data-type which represents the *idea* of a JSON with a primary key-value pair and a secondary/supporting key-value pair, where the key names can be easily changed.

The pseudo-code given below is a generalisation of this idea:

```
data IncomingJson rootname payload = (FromJson payload, ToString rootname) => IncomingJson
  {
    rootname :: payload
  }

data OutgoingJson rootname payload sidename sidepayload = (ToJson payload, ToString rootname, ToJson sidepayload, ToString sidename) => IncomingJson
  {
    rootname :: payload
  , sidename :: sidepayload
  }

createOrder :: IncomingJson "order" NewOrder -> OutgoingJson "order" Order Nothing ()

editOrderItems :: IncomingJson "items" [OrderItem] -> OutgoingJson "items" [OrderItem] "order" Order

editOrderAddress :: IncomingJson "address" Address -> OutgoingJson "address" Address "order" Order
```

Comment: Maybe you just need [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)?

Comment: @freestyle how can lens help in this situation? I'm sorry, but I barely know how to use lens, let alone bend it to such tricky situations.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. You have data-types which represent some information from your application domain and the application has state of this type. Sometimes, some part of this state maybe changed (for example, by request from UI). And you want to have functions which manipulates only parts of this state. But after they will be applyed you want to have the updated state. This is true?

Comment: So, the question is not what I'm trying to do in the app. The core question is how do I represent JSON keys at the type-level in a parameterised manner?

Comment: @freestyle check my edit.

Comment: This pseudocode you give is a far too broad generalization - the first type is just the identity and the 2nd is a pair, with some extra constraints packed inside the type (which you almost certainly do not need to be packed inside the type) and some phantom types. If you want generic *representations of data* then you must want *generic operations on data* - but you've given no example of such operations.

Comment: @user2407038 "If you want generic representations of data then you must want generic operations on data - but you've given no example of such operations" >> For the server the "generic" operation is being able to send a named primary payload and a named secondary payload. The operation is NOT generic at the client/UI end, where it is expecting the primary payload to have a certain name and the secondary payload to have a certain name.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: an attempt at a full answer to the revised question.)

The example code below may be close to what you want.  This example defines `OutgoingJSON` and `IncomingJSON` with custom `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances respectively.  (I included a `ToJSON` for the `IncomingJSON` datatype, too, though I suspect you don't need it.)  It relies on each datatype being assigned a JSON key via a short `KeyedJSON` instance.  It's possible to use `GHC.Generics` or some alternative to automate this, but that seems both ugly and ill-advised.  (You don't *really* want your JSON keys directly tied to Haskell data type names, do you?)

If you load this up and look at the types of `inExample1` and `outExample1`, they should match what you expect.  `inExample2` and `inExample3` demonstrate type-safe parsing of a block of JSON -- it succeeds if the key for the expected type exists in the JSON block and fails if it doesn't.  Finally, `outExample1AsJSON` shows how an `OutgoingJSON` example will be serialized with the desired primary and secondary keys.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module JsonExample where

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C

data Address = Address String deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON, Show)
data OrderItem = OrderItem Int String deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON, Show)
data Order = Order { address :: Address
                   , items   :: [OrderItem]
                   } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON, Show)

class KeyedJSON a              where jsonKey :: a -> Text
instance KeyedJSON Address     where jsonKey _ = "address"
instance KeyedJSON [OrderItem] where jsonKey _ = "orderitems"
instance KeyedJSON Order       where jsonKey _ = "order"

--
-- OutgoingJSON
--

data OutgoingJSON primary secondary
  = OutgoingJSON primary secondary deriving (Show)
instance (ToJSON primary,   KeyedJSON primary,
          ToJSON secondary, KeyedJSON secondary) => 
         ToJSON (OutgoingJSON primary secondary) where
  toJSON (OutgoingJSON prim sec) = 
    object [ jsonKey prim .= toJSON prim
           , jsonKey sec  .= toJSON sec
           ]

--
-- IncomingJSON
--

data IncomingJSON primary 
  = IncomingJSON primary deriving (Show)
-- don't know if ToJSON instance is needed?
instance (ToJSON primary,   KeyedJSON primary) => ToJSON (IncomingJSON primary) where
  toJSON (IncomingJSON prim) =
    object [ jsonKey prim .= toJSON prim ]
instance (FromJSON primary, KeyedJSON primary) => FromJSON (IncomingJSON primary) where
  parseJSON (Object v) = do
    let key = jsonKey (undefined :: primary)
    IncomingJSON <$> (v .: key >>= parseJSON)

-- Simple examples of typed `IncomingJSON` and `OutgoingJSON` values

-- inExample1 :: IncomingJSON Address
inExample1  = IncomingJSON
              (Address "123 New Street")

-- outExample1 :: OutgoingJSON Address Order
outExample1 = OutgoingJSON 
              (Address "15 Old Street") 
              (Order (Address "15 Old Street") [OrderItem 1 "partridge", OrderItem 5 "golden rings"])

-- Reading a JSON address in a type-safe manner
aJSONAddress :: ByteString
aJSONAddress = C.pack "{\"address\":\"123 New Street\"}"

-- This returns a `Just (IncomingJSON Address)`
inExample2 :: Maybe (IncomingJSON Address)
inExample2 = decode aJSONAddress

-- This returns `Nothing`
inExample3 :: Maybe (IncomingJSON Order)
inExample3 = decode aJSONAddress

-- This demonstrates the JSON serialization of outExample1
outExample1AsJSON = encode outExample1
```

Comment: in your example what will `OutgoingJson` serialized to? `{outRootJson: something, outsideJSON: something}` i.e. the actual keys in the JSON won't change, right? The keys will always be `outRootJson` and `outsideJson`, right?

Comment: Check the edit to my question. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: So, the core idea in this new solution is of `KeyedJSON` which decides the rootname for each type. The `ToJSON` instance of `OutgoingJSON primary secondary` uses `KeyedJSON` to decide the roonames for each payload. Ingenious, and seems like it can work!

Comment: btw, why is the signature of `jsonKey :: a -> Text` why can't it simply be `jsonKey :: Text`?

Comment: Also, is it possible to scale this solution to multiple secondary payload, i.e. `OutgoingJSON a0 a1 a2 .. aN`?

Comment: In Haskell, if you could somehow define `jsonKey :: Text`, then that value would have to be constant (because of Haskell's referential transparency -- pure computations return the same value every time they are invoked).  In order to return a different value for different object types, `jsonKey` must be a function that takes an argument (and it's allowed to return a different key for different arguments).  So, even though it *looks* like the `a` argument isn't being used, it is -- it's just that the value is ignored and only the type matters.